# How to specify variable filename in fread

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R script that reads in several text files into data.tables. I use a for loop to step through the filelist to read in each file, which works quite well.

```
dta <- data.table()
for (fname in flist) {
  dt <- data.table(read.csv(fname, header=T, sep=",", comment.char="#"))
  dt$FNAME <- fname
  dta <-rbind(dta,dt)
}
```

In order to speed things up, I decided to try using the fread method from the data.table package. I also decided to use the grep shell command to help the operation,

```
dta <- data.table()
for (fname in flist) {
  dt <- fread('grep RDIST fname', header=F, sep=",")
  dt$FNAME <- fname
  dta <-rbind(dta,dt)
}
```

But I get an error message,

```
grep: fname: No such file or directory
Error in fread("grep RDIST fname", header = F, sep = ",") :
  File is empty: /dev/shm/file2e7efc79ba710d
```

I figured that the problem is the fread command does not parse the fname variable to the actual filename. If I try to use the actual filename instead of the variable this works nicely,

```
> fname
[1] "QualM_Setall_20150901_165011.txt"
> dt <- fread('grep RDIST QualM_Setall_20150901_165011.txt', sep=',', header=F)
Read 4849664 rows and 15 (of 15) columns from 0.283 GB file in 00:00:04
>
```

Is there any way for me to use fname as a variable inside the shell command for fread ?

Thanks & regards,

Derric

Comment: Try concatenating the pieces of the string grep call, like `paste("grep RDIST",fname)`. Also worth noting: growing things is not good practice / efficient in r (referring to your `rbind` inside a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `paste`:

```
dta <- data.table()
for (fname in flist) {
  dt <- fread(paste('grep RDIST', fname), header=F, sep=",")
  dt$FNAME <- fname
  dta <-rbind(dta,dt)
}
```

Comment: Other alternative: `sprintf("grep RDIST %s", fname)`

Comment: As @Frank noted slightly before my answer :( you are over-writing `dta`, which will be slow.  Think about something like: `rbindlist(do.call(fread, paste('grep RDIST', fname), header=F, sep = ',') ) #not tested`

Comment: That could go into the answer itself, though you'll want to paste onto `flist` not `fname`; and maybe add the creation of the `FNAME` column (if you want to be very close to the op's case). I think it's natural/okay that it wouldn't be tested, since the op's case is not presented so as to be repro'd.

Answer (score 7):

Too long for a comment.

You're using the very fast `fread(...)` function in the data.table package to import the data, but you're not taking advantage of the other features of data.table. In particular adding a column to a data.table using, e.g.

```
dt$newCol <- ...
```

is bad practice, as it causes R to make a new copy. Use this instead:

```
dt[,newCol:=...]
```

This is likely to be faster than the loop:

```
library(data.table)
result <- rbindlist(lapply(flist,function(x)fread(paste("grep RDIST",x),header=FALSE, sep=",")[,FNAME:=x]))
```

Note: The code above was tested in a very simple case.

Comment: why not `rbindlist(lapply(` instead of `do.call(rbind, `? should be faster too

Comment: @jangorecki Fair enough. Updated the question.

Comment: Not sure how inefficient this is, but maybe `data.table(FNAME=flist)[, fread(paste("grep RDIST", FNAME), header=FALSE, sep=","), by=FNAME]`